# How to cancel an AsyncTask after it has been executed?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I use AsyncTask with Progress Dialog for downloading a database from a server. I want to provide user with an option of cancellation the downloading task.

My purpose is to dismiss Progress Dialog and cancel AsyncTask when user click on `Cancel button` on Progress Dialog.

I have applied numerous code examples but they help to dismiss Progress Dialog only and fail to stop or cancel the downloading task.

***Regarding my code lines below,*** can you please give a little help? Many thanks.

**EDITED VERSION**

```
public class Download_gram extends Activity {

// File url to download
private static String url = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15034088/Anhroid_Dict/grammar.nvk.zip";
private static DownloadFile newTask; 

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
// Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar) 
public static final int progress_bar = 0; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.download_gram);
    newTask = new DownloadFile();

    startDownload_gram = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar_gram);

    //start download event and show progress bar
    startDownload_gram.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //Checi if file exists 
             File fgram = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/my_Folder/db/my_file/my_file.nvk");
             if(fgram.exists())
             { 
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File installed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
             else
             {

                //checking if the user has an internet connection
                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (info != null) {
                    if (!info.isConnected()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                // execute async task
                    else 
                        //new DownloadFile().execute(url);                          
                    newTask.execute(url);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }                   
             }           

        }});        
    }   

//show progress dialog
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar:
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading… Please wait.");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setMax(100);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dismissDialog(progress_bar);
                newTask.cancel(true);
            }
        });
        progressDialog.show();
        return progressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

//backgroound downloading
    class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(progress_bar);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            while (url != null) {
            int count;              
            try {
                URL url = new URL(args[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int fileLength = conection.getContentLength();
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/_nvk_gram.zip");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/fileLength));
                    // writing data to file
                    os.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                // flush output
                os.flush();             

                os.close();
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
            //Unzip the downloaded zip file 
            {
                String destinationDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/my_Folder/db/my_file/";
                int BUFFER = 2048;
                List<String> zipFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
                File sourceZipFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/_nvk_gram.zip");
                File unzipDestinationDirectory = new File(destinationDirectory);
                unzipDestinationDirectory.mkdir();

                ZipFile zipFile = null;
                // Open Zip file for reading
                try {
                    zipFile = new ZipFile(sourceZipFile, ZipFile.OPEN_READ);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Create an enumeration of the entries in the zip file
                Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> zipFileEntries = zipFile.entries();

                // Process each entry
                while (zipFileEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
                    // grab a zip file entry
                    ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) zipFileEntries.nextElement();

                    String currentEntry = entry.getName();

                    File destFile = new File(unzipDestinationDirectory, currentEntry);
                          //destFile = new File(unzipDestinationDirectory, destFile.getName());

                    if (currentEntry.endsWith(".zip")) {
                        zipFiles.add(destFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    }

                    // grab file's parent directory structure
                    File destinationParent = destFile.getParentFile();

                    // create the parent directory structure if needed
                    destinationParent.mkdirs();

                    try {
                        // extract file if not a directory
                        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                            BufferedInputStream is =
                                    new BufferedInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(entry));
                            int currentByte;
                            // establish buffer for writing file
                            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

                            // write the current file to disk
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
                            BufferedOutputStream dest =
                                    new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);

                            // read and write until last byte is encountered
                            while ((currentByte = is.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                                dest.write(data, 0, currentByte);
                            }
                            dest.flush();
                            dest.close();
                            is.close();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                try {
                    zipFile.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                for (Iterator<String> iter = zipFiles.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                    String zipName = (String)iter.next();
                    doUnzip(
                        zipName,
                        destinationDirectory +
                            File.separatorChar +
                            zipName.substring(0,zipName.lastIndexOf(".zip"))
                    );
                    if(isCancelled())return (null);
                }
            }
            }

            File fav_ifo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/my_Folder/db/my_file/my_file.nvk");
            if(fav_ifo.exists())
            { 
                try {
                    AssetManager am = getAssets();
                    String fileName = "my_file.ifo";
                    File destinationFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/my_Folder/db/my_file/" + fileName);    
                    InputStream in = am.open("my_file.ifo");
                    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);  
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int len1 = 0;
                    while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) { 
                        f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                    }
                    f.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("CopyFileFromAssetsToSD", e.getMessage());    
                }   
            }
            else
            {

            }
           //Delete the downloaded zip
            File folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String fileName = folder.getPath() + "/_nvk_gram.zip";

            File myFile = new File(fileName);
            if(myFile.exists())
                myFile.delete();
                return null; 

                 }          

        private void doUnzip(String zipName, String string) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        //updating progress bar
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            //progress percentage
            progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));   
       }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) { 
            dismissDialog(progress_bar);
            //toast to notify user of download completion
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database successfully downloaded.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Download_gram.this, my_Main_class.class);
                Download_gram.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting progressDialog.setCancelable(true); instead false?

Comment: Thanks to @dougcunha and @Puyover, but I have tried `progressDialog.setCancelable(true);`. This is for BackPress, I think. And it dismisses the dialog only as well and fails to stop the downloading task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see you should keep track of your DownloadFile(aSyncTask) class object.

Create a new variable in your

```
public class Download_gram extends Activity {
    // File url to download
    private static String url = "http://www.abc.123.zip";
    private static DownloadFile newTask; // ADDED BY ME
// ... ...
```

you should save the object reference when you call

```
new DownloadFile().execute("Url String"); //you must be doing this

//instead you should do

newTask = new DownloadFile();
newTask.execute("Url String");  // YOUR OBJECT IS IN newTask
...

// keep track of this newTask variable

// when ever you want to cancel just call
newTask.cancel(true); // ADDED BY ME
dialog.dismiss();//In fact, I want to apply the code to stop both Progress Dialog and AsynTask here.
```

after setting newTask to cancel, you should check timely in doInBackground that is you task is canceled ? if yes then exit doInBackground

```
// YOU CAN USE THIS IN WHILE LOOP OF doInBakcground
if(isCancelled())return (null);
//This will exit doInBackground function and hence cancel task.
// you can perform other operations too in this "if" statement as per your need.
```

for reference of these functions

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)

##################### New Version ################.

you haven't checked is the task is canceled or not. you have to check everywhere downloading is taking place in asynctask if iscancelled is true return (null); to halt asynctask and stop downloading.
you should replace following code:

```
    while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) { // inside doInBackground
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/fileLength));
                // writing data to file
                os.write(data, 0, count);
                if(isCancelled())return (null); // ADDED BY ME
            }
```

above added line is must this will check if task is canceled this doInBackground function should be over.

Comment: Many thanks Cyrus-WS. I have applied your instruction but it still download file in the background. Please have a look at my EDITED version.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think your instructions do help, and the AsyncTask can be cancelled as I wish. However, there is a negative development: if the file already exists, and if I download it again and cancel the AsyncTask, the app gets force-closed. Despite this, I will accept your answer.

Comment: you can check before calling newTask.execute() that if file already exist or not and act accordingly. and if isCancelled() returns true you can again perform actions on that file, as that file is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way,

```
 progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
      public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
          yourAysncTask.cancel(true);
      }
});
```

Comment: Don't forget the call to actually cancel the AsyncTask.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please make it clearer to me with my code above?

Comment: remove that progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();//In fact, I want to apply the code to stop both Progress Dialog and AsynTask here.
            }
        });

Comment: @ADR: Thanks a lot, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should to

```
yourAsyncTask.cancel(true);
```

and, inside your class DownloadFile, you should to check for *isCanceled()* and do a return if true.